# If isospin is only approximately conserved by strong interaction, why do we never see isospin violation?

Tags: symmetry, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force, isospin-symmetry

Due to the mass difference between the $u$-quark and the $d$-quark, SU(2) isospin symmetry is only an approximate symmetry (even in a universe devoid of weak and EM interactions). This suggests to me that isospin violation is not impossible in strong interaction itself. But from what I know, this does not happen. Processes mediated by strong interactions are always found to conserve isospin. Why is this so?

Comment: for the general reader https://faraday.physics.utoronto.ca/PVB/DBailey/SubAtomic/Lectures/LectF09/Lect09.htm